# A variation of Cesaro means

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

It follows from the Cesaro means that
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n g(k)=c~~~{\rm if}~~~\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}g(k)=c.$$

Instead, let us consider a sequence $\{f_n\}$ such that $f_n\rightarrow f$ (uniformly or pointwise).
I'd like to show that 
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n f_n(k)=c~~~{\rm if}~~~\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}f(k)=c.$$

Can anybody help me prove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is trivial if $f_n\to f$ uniformly. Given $\epsilon>0$, if $n$ is large enough then $$\left|\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^nf_n(k)-\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^nf(k)\right|<\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\epsilon=\epsilon$$
and
$$\left|c-\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^nf(k)\right|<\epsilon.$$

Answer (score 0):

*This is not true pointwise*, at least without further assumptions. Take $f=0$ (constant function) and $(f_n)_n$ defined by
$$
f_n(x) = \begin{cases} n& \text{ if } x=n\\ 0& \text{ o.w.}\end{cases}
$$

Then, for any $n$, $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n f_n(k) = \frac{1}{n}f_n(n) = 1$, and yet

- $(f_n)_n$ converges pointwise to $f=0$;
- $\lim_{k\to\infty} f(k) = 0$.

Comment: Thank you so much!! What if $f_n\rightarrow f$ uniformly? The identity seems to hold in many practical cases.

Comment: I'll think about it later (it's early morning here), but please do not edit your question that way -- adding a "Edit:" to mention you are now specifically interested in the uniform convergence is fine, but removing the original question about pointwise is not... if anything, it makes this answer totally irrelevant to the new question, while it was not to the previous.

Comment: It makes sense. I re-edited the question like the previous one. Thanks again.